# rewrite image path to another path and deny from all the original path

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Apologies if my title isn't descriptive enough of my problem.

I'm attempting to lock off access to a certain section of a website (the administration area) with the use of htaccess `Deny from all`. There's assets inside this denied area which still need to be accessed on the front-end, so I have some rewrites which work, until the `Deny from all` is added.

My images actually live here: `/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/`

But I want them to be accessible from here: `/media-uploads/`

I've used the following htaccess code, which works well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^media-uploads/(.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|png))$ wordpress/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L]`
```

With the above I can access `/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg` via the url `/media-uploads/image.jpg`

What I want to do also, is to have `Deny from all` applied to the `/wordpress/` directory. If I add this, it works by denying access, but it also breaks the image rewrites, so a request to `/media-uploads/image.jpg` show me the 403 forbidden page as it should in the `/wordpress/` area.

Can anybody help me? I'm at a bit of a loose-end.

Thanks.

Comment: An `.htaccess` with an `Allow from all` line in the directory `/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/` should override the one in `/wordpress/`

Comment: @apokryfos that's great, and sort of works. But ideally I'd like the image to only be accessible via `/media-uploads/image.jpg` and not accessible via `/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

To block access to the orignal uri, you can use the following condition above your RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

This will return 403 error to clients if they request /wordpress/wp-content/upload/foobar